# Remove hiberfil.sys on a system that doesn't support hibernation

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I upgraded my computer to Intel Xeon 2388G + SuperMicro x12STH-F. I did not reinstall the OS - Windows 10 Pro. Sleep is not supported on my new system(I'm not 100% sure of that - could be result of upgrade without re-install). I think that messes with hybrid sleep or something because hibernate is also not supported. I can't remove hiberfil.sys nor enable/disable hibernate. `powercfg /h off` doesn't do anything
(yes, cmd is running as administrator, and yes, I rebooted after this command).

hiberfil.sys is taking 25GB of my OS partition and if I can't use it I don't want it there. I want to either enable hibernate or remove that file.

I don't have sleep or hibernate in power options:

[image: Advanced Power Options]

**Update:** According to the [Datasheet](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/662318/662318_Intel_Xeon%20E-2300%20Datasheet%20Vol1_Rev001.pdf) the cpu supports sleep (S3) and hibernate (S4). I'm not sure about the motherboard. It could be BIOS setting. I'll ask about that on server site. If I turn on sleep I'm sure I can disable hibernate/hybrid sleep.

Comment: I usually turn off hibernation from the command line see if that works? Open command prompt (as admin), Run `powercfg -h off`

Comment: At the risk of asking a very obvious thing: Did you reboot after pwrcgf -h off?

Comment: Yes, I did. The file won't go away. And can't be deleted either - it's not left over file from previous system. it's locked.

Comment: I probably can delete it, but if windows is locking it, it most likely wants it, so it'll create it again. I will try that though (when I get the chance to close all my work :) )

Comment: Normally, `powercfg -h off` removes the file _immediately_, without rebooting or anything. I suggest running the usual `sfc` and `dism` stuff to make sure the system is somewhat okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into a WinPE environment (e.g. recovery mode or a Windows install USB – both let you open a Command Prompt window using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>), use `attrib -r -h -s C:\hiberfil.sys`, then delete it using regular `del`.

Comment: Deleting file with WinPE worked. I didn't need to do `attrib` - just `del` deleted the file and it didn't come back.